# multiple update array query gone wrong :(

Tags: php, arrays

hey guys im having trouble with an array. all i need is for the query to update 2 columns on the table based on the records id

The table has a column called OffID and it looks for any record that has not yet been authorised. to mark it authorised the user will select a check box for either authorise or deny and then press the submit button. however at the moment i have 9 records which show in the table each with there own unique id but when submit is selected it will only update one. any help in showing where ive gone wrong would be grateful and cheers in advance :)

ok i edited the code but it is only now setting the first record. so if there are 8 records and i choose accept for the first record and deny for the second record both the accept and deny are set to the first record in the database my new code is below

```
    <?php 
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/Apollo/dbc.php";
    include_once($path);
    $rs_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM off WHERE IsItAuthorised='0' and isitsick='0' ORDER BY DayOff");   
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Administration Main Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //Assign each array to a variable
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $approve = $_POST['approve'];
        $deny = $_POST['deny'];
        $limit = count($rs_results); 
    $values = array(); // initialize an empty array to hold the values
        for($k=0;$k<$limit;$k++){
        $msg[] = "$limit New KPI's Added";                  
              $query = "UPDATE off SET Authorised = '$approve[$k]', Deny = '$deny[$k]' WHERE OffID = '$id[$k]'";
        }       
        $Event = "INSERT INTO events (UserName, Event ) VALUES ('$_SESSION[user_name]', 'Entered New KPI' )";
echo $query;
    if (!mysql_query($query,$link)){
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {

            mysql_query($Event);
            echo "<div class=\"msg\">" . $msg[0] . "</div>";
        }
        }                             
    ?>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="14%" valign="top"><?php

    ?>

        </td>
        <td width="74%" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">

          <p><?php 
          if(!empty($msg)) {
          echo $msg[0];
          }
          ?></p>

          <p>
            <?php 
          $cond = '';   
          $sql = "select * from off ";        
          $rs_total = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
          $total = mysql_num_rows($rs_total);         
          ?>        
          <p> 
            <form name "searchform" action="/Apollo/Admin/HolidayRequests.php" method="post">
            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
              <tr class="mytables"> 
                <td width="4%"><font color="white"><strong>ID</font></strong></td>
                <td width="4%"> <font color="white"><strong>Staff Member</font></strong></td>
                <td width="10%"><font color="white"><strong>Day Off</font></strong></div></td>
                 <td width="10%"><font color="white"><strong>Is It Authorized</font></strong></div></td>
                <td width="15%">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
             <tr> 
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="17%"><div align="center"></div></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <?php while ($rrows = mysql_fetch_array($rs_results)) {?>
              <tr> 
                <td><input name="id[]" id="id[]" size="4" value="<?php echo $rrows['OffID'];?>" /></td>
                <td><?php echo $rrows['StaffMember']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($rrows['DayOff']));?></div></td>

                <td> <span id="approve<?php echo $rrows['id']; ?>"> 
                  <?php if(!$rrows['IsItAuthorised']) { echo "Pending"; } else {echo "Authorized"; }?>
                  </span> </td>

                  <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="approve[]" id="approve[]" value="1"> Approve
                <input type="checkbox" name="deny[]" id="deny[]" value="1"> Deny


             </td>
              </tr>

              <?php } ?>
            </table>
              <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>   
          &nbsp;</p>
          <?php  
          ?>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td width="12%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary white-spaces while putting code, specially the lines-white-space..:)

Comment: I would personally change this so it did not list every single record, and post them all at the same time. I would recommend separating the history display, from the approval process, and only updating a single record when editing. The performance on it is going to get incredibly horrible with time, apr 2.8k for 100 people per year. It may start to hit post size limits as it is sending the entire table with every modification, and be very slow to update. I would also note, it would be wise to harden this against SQL injection as it may be possible to drop your entire database.

Comment: it only pulls records which are not authorised and this is looked at every day so theres normally only about 5 records. i just need it to look at which id its currently on and post to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't it because your $id etc isn't passes an array:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$approve = $_POST['approve'];
$deny = $_POST['deny'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$_POST['id']` but nowhere in your `<form/>` do I see any `<input name="id[]"/>` which could provide the data